# Adding a label within a label on PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 to create a label as shown below. However I would like the top of the label to be a different color, and to have separate lines of text in each. Is there a way to accomplish something like this?

[image]

Here is the code I'm using.

```
def CreateModule():
    label = QLabel()
    label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.setStyleSheet("background-color:purple")
    label.setMaximumWidth(300)
    label.setMaximumHeight(200)
    return label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might be possibile to do this using the [limited support Qt provides for html](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html), using a nested layout is usually easier and more object-oriented

```
def createModule():
    container = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    header = QLabel('Title', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    header.setStyleSheet('color: white; background: black;')
    content = QLabel('Lorem ipsum', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    content.setStyleSheet('color: white; background: purple;')
    layout.addWidget(header)
    layout.addWidget(content)
    container.setMaximumSixe(300, 200)
    return container
```